# synchronized method for accessing database with spring and hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, synchronized

I have a table that maintains a sequence number that is used as an identifier for multiple tables (**multiple invoice tables all the tables are using single sequence**).
Whenever i want to insert a new record in invoice table I read the current sequence number from the table and update it with +1.
The problem is when there are multiple requests for new invoice numbers the sequence number returns duplicate numbers.I tried synchronized block but still it returning duplicate values when multiple requests are hitting at same time.

Here is the method to retrieve the sequence number

```java
synchronized public int getSequence(){
  Sequence sequence = getCurrentSession().get(Sequence.class,1); //here 1 is the id of the row
  int number = sequence.getSequenceNumber();
  sequence.setSequenceNumber(number+1);
  getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(sequence);
  return number;
}
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You should get the next number in the sequence in a separate transaction. But to make it extra save, have a look into `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)`

Comment: `synchronized` is useless when you have a server application that will be running multiple copies. Use proper transactions (which Spring makes ridiculously easy).

Comment: Never update a sequence manually. Use db sewuence, autogenerate, or with jpa consider uuid as solution (maybe the best)

Comment: My case is different.The sequence number is maintained on all the three tables.it is unique for all the 3 tables.!

Comment: i think Even transactions also not help in that case.Ex: Take 2 transactions T1 and T2.both are open at different instances. Both are started at same time. T1 is not aware of the T2 changes until it commits. So, Both transaction will read the same sequence number and write the same sequence number.!  @chrylis

Comment: And then transaction T2 will get rolled back because of the conflict and have to restart.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I won't recommend you to use table implementation of the sequence. [Explanation why](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

But if you have to - hibernate knows how to manage it. [Take a look](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-generate-primary-keys/)

And one more thing. I strongly recommend you to implement synchronization on the data base side. Imagine you have 2 instances of your application connected to the same database instance and working simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Using transactions also not worked for me. I tried all the isolations in mysql but nothing helps me. I solved it with below solution.

```
synchronized public int getSequence(){
   Sequence sequence = getCurrentSession().get(Sequence.class,1); //here 1 is the id of the row
   int prevNumber = sequence.getSequenceNumber();
   Query<Sequence> query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("UPDATE Sequence SET sequenceNumber = :number WHERE sequenceNumber = :prevNumber",Sequence.class);
   query.setParameter("number",prevNumber+1);
   query.setParameter("prevNumber",prevNumber);
   int affectedRows = query.executeUpdate();
   if(accectedRows > 0)
      return number;
   else
     throw new Exception();
}
```

So whenever a conflict happens it will throw an exception.